# Problems With ListView?

Tags: android, listview

**My problems**

I'm trying to make an app where you can add an item to a list using an EditText and a ListView. I was using [this website](http://www.android-examples.com/add-item-in-listview-in-android-programmatically/) to help because I don't have much android coding experience, but I had to change the code a bit because I'm using two activities instead of one. It works,  but there are a few problems that I don't know how to fix.

1. You can only add one list item, and then the last one you put disappears and is replaced by the new one.
2. If you leave the ListView activity, the new list item disappears (I think this is why number one is happening)
3. I have it so when you click on one of the items, it goes to an activity (each goes to a different activity), and you can only click on them after you add an item to the list.

**My code**

Questions.java (the ListView activity)

```
package com.example.sylvie.dogwise;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.View;

public class Questions extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listview;
    String[] ListElements = new String[]{
            "How much food should I feed my dog?",
            "How do I teach my dog to sit?"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.QuestionsList);

        final List<String> ListElementsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(ListElements));
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (Questions.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ListElementsArrayList);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Bundle newQuestion = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (newQuestion == null) {
            return;
        }
        String QuestionName = newQuestion.getString("QuestionName");

        ListElementsArrayList.add(QuestionName);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Question_howmuchfoodshouldifeedmydog.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 1) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Question_2.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0 );
                }
            }
        });
    }

    ;

    public void backHomeOnClick(View view) {
        Intent b = new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class);
        startActivity(b);
    }

    public void askAQuestionOnClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AskAQuestion.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are inserting one item into the list:

```
 String QuestionName = newQuestion.getString("QuestionName");
 ListElementsArrayList.add(QuestionName);
```

If you want to add multiple items at once you can pass a list instead.

You have to store data if you wanna keep it. Check tutorials on realm or dbflow. Choose one that fits your use case the most.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why I can't click on an item until I add one?

Comment: debug the app and check the onItemClick method to see which values of position it holds. That should tell you what are you doing wrong.